# WebBrowser object content changes position when form is minimized and then restored

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I've written a C# app that uses a webbrowser for its main content window. The program loads a rather large amount of text into that browser, which works fine. I've noticed when reading that content, however, that if I minimize the application and then restore it that the position jumps way up in the text instead of remaining where it was. Doing this several times puts the text at the top of the content.

Any ideas what could cause this and what I could do to stop this behavior? It's only when I minimize/restore, if I alt-tab into another application and go back the position is properly retained.

Here are screenshots of the content: 
Before minimizing: http://imageshack.us/a/img641/9632/beforeminimize.jpg
After restore: http://imageshack.us/a/img827/439/afterrestore.jpg

Here is a link to the code on GitHub, though I haven't changed any properties of the WebBrowswer aside from its anchors: https://github.com/benroth/FanBook

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which browser you're speaking about?

Comment: It's just a webbrowser object in the program. Toolbox/WebBrowser.

Comment: He is using the `WebBrowser` Control. @Ben, please show code. And/or pics.

Comment: I've edited my original post to add both, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the below steps:

1. Open Windows form in design mode.
2. Select Web Browser Control > Goto > Properties.
3. Specify [Dock] property to None.
4. In code behind, specify the height and width for the Web Browser Control.

I do have the similar problem and got fixed following the above steps.

Comment: I do have the control docked, but it's not a functionality I want to lose--the webbrowser being resizable makes it so that it can be usable both as the primary function of the program (downloading a large set of online story chapters into a single document) and the secondary function of reading it natively in the program rather than having to save the document and opening elsewhere. Being unable to resize the application to a comfortable viewing size seriously impacts the second function.

I'll try doing this to confirm the cause, but will definitely look for a workaround if that's it. Thanks!